# How do I count the occurrences of a factor in several columns, grouping by one column?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a seemingly simple question, but I cannot figure out how to get exactly what I want.

My data looks like this:

```
      Job     C/C++     Java     Python
  Student     FALSE     TRUE      FALSE
Developer      TRUE     TRUE       TRUE
Developer      TRUE     TRUE      FALSE
 Sysadmin      TRUE    FALSE      FALSE
  Student     FALSE     TRUE       TRUE
```

I would like to group by the "Job" column and count the number of `TRUE`s in each column. My desired output would look like this:

```
      Job     C/C++     Java     Python
  Student         0        2          1
Developer         2        2          1 
 Sysadmin         1        0          0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe what you have tried so far in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternative `plyr` and `data.table` solutions:

**data.table:**

```
require(data.table)
tmp.dt <- data.table(temp, key="Job")
tmp.dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=Job]

#         Job C.C.. Java Python
# 1: Developer     2    2      1
# 2:   Student     0    2      1
# 3:  Sysadmin     1    0      0
```

**plyr:**

```
require(plyr)
ddply(temp, .(Job), function(x) colSums(x[-1]))

#         Job C.C.. Java Python
# 1 Developer     2    2      1
# 2   Student     0    2      1
# 3  Sysadmin     1    0      0
```

**Edit:** If instead of TRUE/FALSE, you've to count the number of `Newbie`'s, then:

With data.table:

```
require(data.table)
tmp.dt <- data.table(temp, key="Job")
tmp.dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x == "Newbie")), by=Job]
```

With plyr:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(temp, .(Job), function(x) colSums(x[-1] == "Newbie"))
```

Comment: I much prefer the data.table answer here, but it is nice to have alternatives.

Comment: This is very nice and I think I will use this solution. Another question though: what would you do if the data were not TRUE/FALSE, but instead an arbitrary string. Like if I were interested in counting the number of "Newbie"s in Python?

Comment: @user2145843, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note the "Ask Question" button you would have clicked to ask your first question. Your follow-up question in this comment is different enough to be considered a different question. But, do also be sure to *search* for any similar questions before asking a new question.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your data.frame is called "temp", just use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(. ~ Job, temp, sum)
#         Job C.C.. Java Python
# 1 Developer     2    2      1
# 2   Student     0    2      1
# 3  Sysadmin     1    0      0
```

---

The logic is that `TRUE` and `FALSE` equate to numeric values of "1" and "0", so you can simply use `sum` when aggregating.

---

And, to add the "tidyverse" solution for completeness:

```
library(tidyverse)
temp %>% 
  group_by(Job) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum)
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Job       C.C..  Java Python
#   <chr>     <int> <int>  <int>
# 1 Developer     2     2      1
# 2 Student       0     2      1
# 3 Sysadmin      1     0      0
```

---

Here's your data in a format that is easy to copy-and-paste. This was obtained by using `dput(your-actual-data-frame-name)` and is what you should use in the future when posting R questions to Stack Overflow.

```
temp <- structure(list(Job = c("Student", "Developer", "Developer", "Sysadmin", 
          "Student"), C.C.. = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), Java = c(TRUE, 
          TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), Python = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
          .Names = c("Job", "C.C..", "Java", "Python"), class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```