# R - Compare two data frames of different length for same values in two columns

Tags: r, compare

This is a question about how to compare several columns of two different data frames with varying length.

I have two data frames (data from receiver1 (rec1) and receiver2 (rec2)) of different lengths containing positions for 4 different ships:

```
rec1 <- data.frame(name = sample (c("Nina", "Doug", "Alli", "Steve"), 20, replace = TRUE), 
                lon = sample (1:20), 
                lat = sample (1:10)
                )    
rec2 <- data.frame(name = sample (c("Nina", "Doug", "Alli", "Steve"), 30, replace = TRUE), 
                lon = sample (1:30),
                lat = sample (1:30)
                )
```

They contain varying names (ship names, same names for both) and longitude (lon) as well as latitude (lat) coordinates.

I am attempting to compare the two dfs to see how many values in both "lon" AND "lat" match for each vessel (i.e. how often the two receivers picked up the same locations)

Basically I am trying to find out how good each receiver is and how much of the datapoints overlap (e.g. percentage).

I am not sure how this is best done and am open for any suggestions. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a modified and reproducible test case together with my answer. I designed the test set to include combinations that will match and some that will not match.

```
rec1 <- data.frame(shipName = rep(c("Nina", "Doug", "Alli", "Steve"), each = 5), 
                lon = rep.int(c(1:5), 4), 
                lat = rep.int(c(11:15), 4)
                )    
rec2 <- data.frame(shipName = rep(c("Nina", "Doug", "Alli", "Steve"), each = 7), 
                lon = rep.int(c(2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6), 4),
                lat = rep.int(c(12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16), 4)
                )

print(rec1)
print(rec2)

#Merge the two data frames together, keeping only those combinations that match
m <- merge(rec1, rec2, by = c("shipName", "lon", "lat"), all = FALSE)

print(m)
```

If you want to count how many times each combination appears, try the following. (There are different ways to aggregate. Some are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280362/in-r-how-do-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-factor-in-several-columns-and-group-by). Below is my preferred method, which requires you to have `data.table` installed. It's a great tool, so you may want to install it if you haven't yet.)

```
library(data.table)

#Convert to a data table and optionally set the sort key for faster processing
m <- data.table(m)
setkey(m, shipName, lon, lat)

#Aggregate and create a new column called "Count" with the number of
    #observations in each group (.N)
m <- m[, j = list("Count" = .N), by = list(shipName, lon, lat)]

print(m)

#If you want to return to a standard data frame rather than a data table:
m <- data.frame(m)
```

Comment: Kevin, that is a very neat and nice solution that worked perfectly for me. Thanks so much for taking the time and effort!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't construct a very useful test case, but here is an approach:

```
> both <- rbind(data.frame(grp="A", rec1[, 2:3]), data.frame(grp="B", rec2[, 2:3]))
> with(both, table( duplicated(both[,2:3]), grp))
       grp
         A  B
  FALSE 20 30
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and sorry that the test case is no good, as I wasn't sure how to do it I just went for a simple example.

Comment: The code you provide works nicely, thanks so much! What I wonder, it seems from the output that it matches only Lon with Lon and Lat with Lat of the two data sets respectively, and is not looking for identical pairs of Lon and Lat. Or am I getting that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that was my intent. I didn't think that Lat and Lon were interchangeable.

Comment: I think I got the solution, but I certainly learned a new interesting code with the grp. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make this comparison in base R is with `merge`.

Try this:

```
# Set the RNG so sample() produces the same output and this example is reproducible
set.seed(720) 

rec1 <- data.frame(name = sample (c("Nina", "Doug", "Alli", "Steve"), 20, replace = TRUE), 
            lon = sample (1:20), 
            lat = sample (1:10)
            )    
rec2 <- data.frame(name = sample (c("Nina", "Doug", "Alli", "Steve"), 30, replace = TRUE), 
            lon = sample (1:30),
            lat = sample (1:30)
            )

merged <- merge(x = rec1,
                y = rec2,
                by = c("name","lat","lon"))

print(merged)
```

The merged data frame will contain all of the cases where all three columns match (in this case, one). You could then do something like `table(merged$name)` to count the number of times each name appears in the merged data.

Though, your question leaves me wondering... there must be some sort of time element here, yes? If you include the measurement time in your data, you could merge by *name* and *time*, then calculate the measured *lat* and *lon* differences.

**Edit:**

I feel I would be remiss if I didn't mention the fabulous [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr#dplyr) package, which makes analysis like this extremely simple. The above merge and count of unique name values is achieved with this simple one-liner:

```
inner_join(rec1, rec2) %>% count(name)
```